# SSIS Job Execution Issue: Connection Errors and Read-Only Database

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, oledbexception

I've set up a job in SQL Server that needs to be executed daily. This job involves an SSIS package, which retrieves Excel files from a directory on another server and populates tables in a database. Unfortunately, the job is failing with the following error:

> Source error failed validation and returned error 0xC020801C
> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CONNATACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.\ The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "source excel" failed with error code 0xC0202009. There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. STG_DIM An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine' Hresult: 0x80004005. Description: *Mise à jour impossible. La base de données ou l'objet est en lecture seule.

When I execute the packages from the Integration Server catalog, there is no issue. However, this problem only occurs when the job runs.

My connection to the SQL Server is through Windows authentication.

Comment: You need to create an [SQL Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver16) to run your SQL Agent job.

Comment: I created one, but it still has an error, failed to connect to the path of the source file

Comment: When you run the package, your credentials are being presented to the operating system and used to navigate the path to the Excel file. When you run the job, no proxy, it is using the Account associated to the SQL Agent. If you define a Proxy User of your domain user, *Update the Job* to execute as the new Proxy User, then the proxied version of yourself will reach out to the operating system to navigate the file path. If that does not work, then your likely culprits are: 32 vs 64 bit drivers and then mounted network drives instead of UNC paths.